# Share in inbox in Google Apps Standard

Tags: email, g-suite

I have recently signed up for the Standard account of Google apps. In my company I have certain email addresses that are handled by multiple users. For example the support emails are handled by multiple users.

Now I have just multiple users log into the same account, but this is not a good practice. It can get quite messy when some emails are handled by different users but on the same email address.

Now I looked into the groups option. I have made a group for support@mydomain.com, and added all the users to the group. Now everybody gets a copy of the support message sent. But its got a bigger mess because the users don't know who handles which message. Is there some workaround to this so I can make good use of this all in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we put in a ticket system, we would just hit "reply all" so that a copy of the reply went to support@mydomain.com, and then everyone would know that the issue has been looked after; there's really not much else you can do with e-mail.

You may also want them to use the Star option or better yet, use labels for "opened" and "closed" and have them assign the label depending on the state of the ticket.

Comment: Ok so everybody in the group will be getting the new message, that is fair. The emails will be piling up quite fast tho. But I will look at this alternative. +1

Comment: You really only need to "reply all" once -- after that, the user can just reply to the customer directly.  See my edit above re: using labels.